# Jsoup query on Google Play page

Tags: google-play, jsoup

I'm trying to pull the text from the Permission Details page from a typical Google App page using Jsoup. For example, the permission details from this url. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imangi.templerun

[image]

[image]

I'm not very well versed with JSoup, so I'm not sure of the elements I should be targeting to achieve the effect. I've tried the following:

```
Elements permission= doc.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("class", "permission-bucket");

for(Element p :permission)
{
try{
 p.select("span[class=bucket-title]").text();
 }
catch (Exception e)
{
tv.setText("Error in reading & storing permissions: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

But it is throwing null.  Any help?

Comment: Perhaps could you provide the specific URL you are trying to parse ?

Comment: Hello, can you explain how u reached to the solution?